# How to delete a string only containing a word using regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

```
1 line: "*hello:  "
2 line: "*hello:    "
3 line: "*hello: person answered"
```

Would like to delete line 1 and 2 entirely, but want to keep line 3, without it becoming:

```
"*hello:person answered"
```

tried:

```
line = line.replaceAll("*hello:(\\s*)","");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do

```
line = line.replaceAll("^\\*hello:\\s*$","");
```

or

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\*hello:\\s*(?!.*\\w)","");
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/24

Comment: @SashaSalauyou `negative lookahead` will make sure there is no `letter` afterthe spaces

Comment: Worked for some cases. Thank you!